# get names and values of a form post

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

in asp.net c#

how can you get all the names and values of a form that has been posted?
i.e the field names are unkown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Loop over all the items in Request.Form.

-- Edit:

Like so:

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form){
    Response.Write(key + "=" + Request.Form[key]);
}
```